# How to add button after create/import button on Odoo 11

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11, qweb, custom-button

I write button.xml and qweb in **manifest**.py but it not worked.

button.xml (static/src/xml/button.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates>
    <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
        <t t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="after">
            <button name="xxx" type="button" t-if='widget.modelName == "billing.info.functions"'
                    class="btn btn-sm btn-default o_import_button o_import_import">Upload
            </button>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

**manifest**.py

```
'qweb': [
        "static/src/xml/button.xml"
    ],
```

Comment: Try First Only this code : <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default o_import_button o_import_import">Upload</button>
If it is visible then try to add the condition based on the object it only visible.

Comment: Button is showed when I remove condition. how to use condition for button.

Answer (score 0):

Pairat Atichart

`XML` File `Code` to add the `button`:

Add the custom `class` to manage the visibility of the button [**oe_list_button_custom_class**]

```
<t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="after">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default oe_list_button_custom_class">Upload</button>
    </t>
</t>
```

`JS` `Code` to handle visibility and other operation:

```
var ListController = require('web.ListController');
ListController.include({
    renderButtons: function($node) {
        var self = this;
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        var button = $(this.$buttons.find('.oe_list_button_custom_class'));
        button.css("display", "none");
        if (this.modelName == "billing.info.functions") {
            button.css("display", 'inline');
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: thank you for answer but now I change requirement and i have problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62827165/how-to-add-custom-menu-in-action-when-click-selected-odoo11

Comment: Yes but for this question, if this suggestion is work for you then feel free to accept for in future anyone can have trust in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to extend ImportView insted of ListView as like below:

<templates>
    <t t-extend="ImportView.import_button">
        <t t-jquery="button.o_button_import" t-operation="after" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary o_import_import">
                <span><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i></span>
                Load File
            </button>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```